# add class when a div touch the top of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone I am trying to add class to a div when this div touches the top of the browser .
it is easy for specific div on the page like that

```
$window.scroll(function(){
    var windowTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        sectionTouchTop = $('.section').offset().top();
    if( windowTop >= sectionTouchTop-90){
        $('.section').addClass('hope');
    }
});
```

but what i want is a code that is general for all divs that have attribute [touching=""]
and when the div of this attr touches the top of browser, value of this attr is added as a class for this div

```
$window.scroll(function(){
    var windowTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        sectionTouchTop = $('[touching]').offset().top();
    if( windowTop >= sectionTouchTop-90){
        $('[touching]').addClass( $(this).attr(touching) );
    }
});
```

any help please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To better help you out, can you post some of the code you've written so far?

Comment: I would advice you to add some code into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the logic for doing this, try running the following snippet

```js
$(window).on("scroll", () => {
  $("[touching]").each(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr("touching")
    var offset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    if (offset <= 0) {
      $(this).addClass(className)
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass(className)
    }
  })
}).trigger("scroll")
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.demo {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.offset {
  height: 500px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.top {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
<div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
```